# How add information to Blackberry Maps using BB10 webworks?

Tags: maps, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry 10 webworks, and I want to be able to locate a city using its latitude and longitude. Once a location has been clicked, I want to show some information about the location.
 How can I do this in blackberry 10 webworks?

Answer (score 0):

The [Geolocation API](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/navigator.geolocation.html) allows you to get or watch a position (latitude/longitude). [This sample](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-HTML5-Geolocation-in-your-Web-or-BlackBerry-WebWorks/ta-p/630406) shows how to use it.

You can invoke the *Maps application* with a lat/lon as an argument, to show the location. Look for *MapsArgument* in the *Invoke* API in the docs.

If you want to find the nearest city to a lat/lon, I'm not sure if WebWorks has such an API (yet) but you could use a *gazetteer* (see Wikipedia for info about it). There will be many freely available ones. I would suggest trying to query an online one via a web service.

Similarly, I would try to find online materials to show information about the location. Such as looking up the city in Wikipedia.

Good luck.